# How to display shipping address in Invoice report in Odoo9

Tags: python, odoo-9, qweb

I have created a custom invoice report in odoo9. In that I want to display the customer shipping address. I displayed it in odoo10 like :

```
<b> Name: </b><t t-esc="o.partner_shipping_id.name"/><br/>
<b> Address: </b><t t-esc="o.partner_shipping_id.street"/><br/>
```

But while using it in Odoo9, it is throwing below error.

```
QWebException: "'account.invoice' object has no attribute 'partner_shipping_id'" while evaluating
```

'o.partner_shipping_id.name'

Could someone help me regarding this?

Comment: In odoo 8, the model `account.invoice` has not a such field

Comment: In odoo 8, add this `<address t-field="o.partner_id" t-field-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: true}"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it displays only the customer address. I want to display the shipping address as well. I don't know if Odoo8 and Odoo9 has similar fields, but I am using Odoo9. Any other suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

```
<div t-field="o.partner_id" t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name"], "no_marker": True, "phone_icons": False}'/>
```

this code give full details of customer address

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to get the shipping address from the 'Sale Order'because at the account.invoice level there have only partner name,So for your call if you want shipping address at account invoice level then you might get from sale order level.

These just one prio,so might be it helped you.

Comment: This should be a comment.